# What occurs when you put a relative element inside an absolute element?

Tags: html, css

Absolute: Ignores flow completely. 
Relative: Is within context of normal flow, but can be moved around too.

**This displays a green box within a red box as expected.**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lets see what occurs</title>
    <style>
        #box_1 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 100px;
            right: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            background:red;
        }

        #box_2 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            bottom: 100px;
            left: 40px;
            right: 0px;
            background:green;
            }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box_1"><div id="box_2"></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**How come this fails to do the same?**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lets see what occurs</title>
    <style>
        #box_1 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 100px;
            right: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            background:red;
        }

        #box_2 {
            position: relative;
            top: 100px;
            bottom: 100px;
            left: 40px;
            right: 0px;
            background:green;
            }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box_1"><div id="box_2"></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: specifying all the `top, left, bottom, right` works only for absolute position. For `relative` position, you can just specify the `top` **or** `bottom`, `left` **or** `right` and the size of the element should also be specified, otherwise it will be `0` and you won't see anything.

Comment: box 2 is in the flow of box 1 and it takes it(1) as reference once it(1) is positionned either as : relative,absolute or fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative position:
Even if the content of the relatively positioned element is moved, the reserved space for the element is still preserved in the normal flow.

Absolute position:
With absolute positioning, an element can be placed anywhere on a page. The heading below is placed 100px from the left of the page and 150px from the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

`absolute` positioning is referenced to the parent/ancestor that has `absolute` or `relative` positioning. `relative` positioning is referenced to himself, that's it, to its supposed place in the page flow. So when you position an `absolute` `div` inside another `absolute` `div`, the left/top/etc. references are about the parent's borders; when you position the child `div` like `relative`, it takes reference about his own borders, in the place it was supposed to be.

Here you can read a good article about it: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not using relative positioning inside an absolutely positioned div, it's that you're setting values for every edge (top, right, bottom and left), and your elements have no defined widths. When you set values for every edge, it will attempt to position your element to each of those values which will produce unexpected results.

The following:

```
#box_1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Should be more like:

```
#box_1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

Look at this fiddle to see the positioning working as expected when I remove two unnecessary position values and add width/height: http://jsfiddle.net/S4fvs/9/

Sometimes you want to take up the entire window, so setting `top: 0`, `right: 0`, `bottom: 0` and `left: 0` will cause a block level element to fill all available space. That's useful for creating a new context on top of your normal content, say for a modal that might get long and scroll without scrolling the page behind it.